# getting a list of aliases by domain from a zimbra server via soap admin api

Tags: api, soap, zimbra

I've been reading through the admin api reference documents, but I can't seem to find a way to list aliases already created for the domain.

There is, of course, the addAccountAlias command:

```
<AddAccountAliasRequest id="{value-of-zimbra-id}" alias="{alias}" />
```

And the removeAccountAlias command:

```
<RemoveAccountAliasRequest [id="{value-of-zimbra-id}"] alias="..." />
```

But I don't see a method to retrieve aliases for a domain. getAllAccounts and getAllDistributionLists don't return them.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

This is the api documentation I'm referencing: [Zimbra SOAP Api Reference](http://files.zimbra.com/docs/soap_api/8.0/soapapi-zimbra-doc/api-reference/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, the aliases for any given account are found in an attribute of the account called "zimbraMailAlias" in the GetAccount/GetAllAccounts response.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Header><context xmlns="urn:zimbra"><change token="2499"/></context></soap:Header><soap:Body><GetAllAccountsResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraAdmin">
<account id="343058d1-0b31-4aad-8cc5-1bd819a597a5" name="someone@somewhere.com">
...
<a n="zimbraMailAlias">alias1@somewhere.com</a>
<a n="zimbraMailAlias">alias2@somewhere.com</a>
...
</account></GetAllAccountsResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```